# Blue Imp post_max_size errors do not agree with phpinfo()

Tags: php, file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blue Imp to upload very large MP3 files into /audio/episodes from /admin.

I have phpinfo() files in document root and /audio/episodes and /admin. All of them display

[image: postmax]

[image: upload_max]

But Blue Imp is reporting "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini" on files as small as 5MB.

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server requires an .htaccess in a directory to get the config file loaded.

Once I added an .htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/
</IfModule>
```

to /js/blueimp/server/php/ where the upload work is done the issue was finally reslved.